How would Earth's plants change in this speculated Earth-like planet?
In a revival of one of my older questions, A Habitable Zone Within a Habitable Zone, this Earthlike planet orbits a binary of yellow suns, which by itself orbits a binary of red giants.  (Lifespan is not relevant to this question.)  But as to how this planet deals with the massive spikes in radiation as a result of the two habitable zones overlapping, its ozone layer is one inch thick (eight times thicker than ours) and its magnetic field measures in at 12 gauss.  (By comparison, our magnetic field doesn't get any stronger than 0.65 gauss.)
A year on this planet lasts 496 72-hour days, which translates to 1,488 Earth days, or over four Earth years.  Its orbital shape is perfectly circular, so that each season lasts exactly 124 days, or 372 Earth days, or one week longer than one Earth year.  During the summer, all four stars share the sky together, resulting in a day of 93,000 lux, or 93 percent as bright as a day on Earth.  At the same season, nights are seven to eight times brighter due to its moon’s aluminum crust, a metal that can reflect 95 percent of any light.  But during the winter, the planet is so far from its two suns that “daylight” is basically 36 hours of twilight, and the primary binary shares the “night” sky with the moon.  (It has an axial tilt, but I haven't decided on which degree.)
Now, in this scenario, the planet has been terraformed so that it has an atmosphere that is 35 percent oxygen (as high as in the Carboniferous) and has 2,300 parts per million of carbon dioxide.  Plants that originated from Earth, a planet with a single sun and shorter days, years and seasons, have been planted to colonize this more extreme Earthlike planet.  Against the multiple suns, longer days and longer seasons, the plants adapt to these extremes.  How would they do that?
Oh, and before you ask as to which plants I'm referring to, as different species have different requirements, I'm being more general.  Also, as far as evolutionarily speaking, I'm limiting to the first few generations of colonization.

This falls down on the "can't write a book" level sorry.


Against the multiple suns, longer days and longer seasons, the plants adapt to these extremes. How would they do that?


as far as evolutionarily speaking, I'm limiting to the first few generations of colonization.

Evolution doesn't happen with the snap of a finger after whispering abracadabra, it takes hundreds of generations for something to happen.
Therefore the simple answer to your question with the current premises is that the plants will look like whatever the colonists brought with them with the first generation.
Take a look at plants grown in Iceland: thanks to the long light hours during summer they grow bigger in the greenhouses, but they are still the same species grown anywhere else on Earth.

A few evergreens may survive
There are three major problems with dropping Earth plants into this alien ground:

Ground-up rock is not soil.  There needs to be a whole microbiological ecosystem to make soil that plants can grow in, this will need to be introduced along with the plants.  However, the problem with this is the microbes may not survive the prolonged cold conditions of winter, or insufficient numbers will survive to keep the soil fertile.
Annual species will not survive winter.  An annual species grows, drops seeds and dies.  If there is enough light to trigger the seeds to germinate and start growing but not enough to let them complete growth and create seeds of their own then that species is dead.  It could be grown under controlled conditions by humans that keep seed stock and choose when to expose them to conditions that will allow germination, but they will not reproduce in the wild.  The "wild" sections of the planet will need to be seeded with genetically engineered "annual" species that are adapted for a radically different life cycle, barring an extraordinary mutation in the single generation that grows in "autumn", native Earth species will not survive outside of cultivated areas.
The pollinators will not survive.  Bees will not survive a year-long winter, which means that all the species that rely on bees will not reproduce either.  (Exception:  Bees kept in beehives in climate controlled areas ie greenhouses.)  Yes, there are some other pollinators, eg hummingbirds, but bees are the critical one (and hummingbirds will die in a long winter even faster than bees).

In short, greenhouses with crops, beehives and artificial light/heat will allow Earth plants to be grown.  Out in the wild, only a few evergreen species that do not rely on insect pollination and that have very hardy microbes have any chance of surviving through the first 1,488 Earth-day long "year" on this planet.

Against the multiple suns, longer days and longer seasons, the plants adapt to these extremes. How would they do that?
Firstly survival of the fittest. Species that couldn't cope would be wiped out very quickly. Other species would see a strong selection pressure to adapt and a large number of individuals would also die the first year even from species that could survive as there is often wide genetic variation within a species and unfit variants would die. Those that remained could (see note) potentially then produce offspring that would slowly evolve to better fit their habitat, but that process would be very slow.
The sorts of things that might be expected would be adaptations to different forms of pollination (wind), the development of timing mechanisms based on heat and light that would allow germination at the appropriate time. These already exist but would be changed and refined to the new environment. Eventually planets would evolve to tolerate lower light levels as well.
In the fullness of time (millions of years) evolution by natural selection and the near endless array of permutations and possibilities provide by biochemistry would find a way to fill your planet with life, but it is not possible to predict exactly how this would happen.

It is likely that without assistance many species would get wiped out.
The basic idea is that every time a plant gives off seeds they change slightly.  Some plants may take hundreds of years to adapted on their own or they may never adapt.
One way to handle this is to use a large number of greenhouse to slowly expose the plants to the planets natural conditions.  This would give them time to evolve naturally, but some species may not survive.
Even now on earth farmers are using genetically engineered seeds, so you could use these techniques to help plants grow on your planet.
As far surviving extreme condition grass for example goes into hibernation of some kind.  Winter here gets cold sometimes as low as -5F (colder with windchill) and yet the grass springs to life every summer.

The most likely outcome would be that the hardiest, oldest, and simplest of plants would dominate the environment and push away their less robust competition, until it is all dead and converted to fertilizer.
Given the conditions you described, I would imagine a planet covered in algae slime, moss, lichen, and occasional ferns. Simple fungi and moulds would do well there, as long as there is anything to eat.
The hardiest types of grass or grass-like plants might survive there like the Antarctic hair grass etc, but they too would be limited to places with somehow enriched soils, not sheer rock.
Basically, look up the small islands South of New Zealand and towards Antarctica, some isles around Iceland, and examples of lampenflora: that is your best case scenario.
